# Firebase facebook auth not working on secondary device - Android

Tags: android, facebook, firebase

I've just integrated Facebook auth into my Firebase app.  When using *my* Samsung galaxy edge 7, the authStateListener in MainActivity returns null and am able to create an intent to open the LoginActivity which has a "continue with facebook" button.

But when I installed the app on my SO's phone (Samsung Galaxy 7), the authstatelistener returns a non-null token, even though nobody's logged in.

In fact, it doesn't open facebook or anything, just proceeds with the location permission request.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {



Button popInButton;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

final static String TAG = "Main Activity";
final static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 101;

private boolean startedFromPermissions = false;

LocationManager lm;

Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.context = this;
    popInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pop_in_button);


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {


            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {

                DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("currentPops");

                    userRef.setValue(null);


                } else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();


                }
            }
        });

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

        }

    }
    popInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!isRunning) {
                startForegroundService();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);

            } else if(startedFromPermissions) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);

           }else{
                startForegroundService();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}









@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startedFromPermissions = true;
                startForegroundService();

                return;




            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "You need to allow location services to use this thing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;

            }


        }

    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}




private void startForegroundService(){
    System.out.println("Starting the Serviceeeeeeeeeeeee");
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PopService.class);
    mIntent.putExtra("STATE", "FOREGROUND");
    startService(mIntent);
}



}
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
-T

Comment: to figure this out, just Log the user's id. then go to firebase and see if its an actual user or not.

Comment: @Dreamers Org Just checked the logs, and the user is not on firebase.  Any ideas?

Comment: try just doing if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()!=null) // users exists
else // user does not exist. instead of using a authstatelistener

Comment: @Dreamers Org It's strange, when I did the log and checked the uid, it was for an old uid which I deleted from firebase console in the authentication section.  Any idea why it's still showing?  I uninstalled the app and reinstalled it, but it still shows the same old uid.  Thanks

Comment: No. sounds like ghost data or google automatically logggin you in (which shouldnt be the case after an install)